# How can i call OUT parameter in PROCEDURE via Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

How can i call  OUT parameter in PROCEDURE via Npgsql

I am getting this error when i run below code

-- PostgreSQL 14 -> PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_add_users_new(arrJsnUsers JSON[], jOut OUT JSON) AS $$
DECLARE
    intSpStatus INT;
    v json;
BEGIN
   FOREACH v IN ARRAY arrJsnUsers
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO tbl_user (vhr_name, vhr_password, sin_record_status)
      VALUES(v->>'strName', v->>'strPassword', (v->>'intRecordStatus')::SMALLINT);
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
   intSpStatus = 1;
   jOut['intSpStatus'] = intSpStatus;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

--Dot net core 5

```cs
using (NpgsqlConnection objCon = new NpgsqlConnection("..."))
{
    objCon.Open();
    using (NpgsqlCommand objSqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL sp_add_users_new(:p1, :p2)", objCon))
    {
        // Parameters
        NpgsqlParameter[] lstSqlParameter = {
            new NpgsqlParameter("p1", NpgsqlDbType.Array|NpgsqlDbType.Json) {
                Value = lstUsers,
                DataTypeName = "arrJsnUsers"
            },
            new NpgsqlParameter("p2", NpgsqlDbType.Json) {
                Value = jOut,
                DataTypeName = "jOut",
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            },
        };
        objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(lstSqlParameter);

        // Execute
        IDataReader objDataReader = objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
    objCon.Close();
}
```

--Error

```
42703: column "p2" does not exist
```

Comment: But after adding that colon i am getting this error   Parameter 'p2' referenced in SQL but is an out-only parameter

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see that was an OUT parameter. Disregard what I said. I would recommend adding `npgsql` and `c#` tags so that more knowledgeable people than me will see this question.

Comment: I would say you have long way to go. 1. `jOut['intSpStatus'] = intSpStatus;` is invalid. json does not support subscript '[]' operator. only jsonb support. 2. If the store procedure have out parameter, if you call it, THERE MUST BE ANOTHER EXECUTION BLOCK to hold the returned value. see demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5fff291e3e2034c249fee044570e8b88.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a sample which works - it's recommended to read the [Npgsql docs on this](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#inout-parameters). Some comments:

- You don't specify the output parameter in SQL - just pass a NULL as per the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html).
- Since @p2 is an output parameter, it makes no sense to specify its value (`jOut1` above).
- DataTypeName (`jOut` above) also doesn't make sense here; that's used to indicate to Npgsql which PG type to send for *input* parameters (similar to NpgsqlDbType).

```cs
using var objCon = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Username=test;Password=test");
objCon.Open();

using var objSqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL sp_add_users_new(@p1, NULL)", objCon);

// Parameters
var lstUsers = new[] { @"{ ""Foo"": ""Bar"" }" };

NpgsqlParameter[] lstSqlParameter = {
    new NpgsqlParameter("p1", NpgsqlDbType.Array|NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = lstUsers, DataTypeName = "arrJsnUsers"},
    new NpgsqlParameter("p2", NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output},
};
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(lstSqlParameter);

// Execute
IDataReader objDataReader = objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
Console.WriteLine(objSqlCommand.Parameters[1].Value);
```